# How to discover all restApi of a services without reboot using spring cloud

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

We took a micro service solution base on spring cloud and spring boot.Now we have a Netty project as a IoT protocol service, how can this netty service keep running (beacuse it need to maintain the connect) and discover all api of a new service which registered to eureka.

Comment: you can make a common api for querying all rest apis of this service.

Comment: What is happening? You haven't described very much? Eureka, and most service registry and discovery services, are designed to work without restarting your processes.

Comment: I know we can registry new service without restart Eureka, but how to access all api of a new service with restart other service .For example , service A  is registered and had setup some rule to interact with new service. When a new  service which implement those rule registered to Eureka, how can service A discovery this new service and access its api without restart.

Comment: There is no functionality to determine what APIs a service exposes via spring cloud.

Comment: I search a lot, it seem ribbon-eureka would work, but cannot found a specify example.